# VueJS - Module not found issue while importing a component

Tags: vue.js

[image]I've a fiel name **Countries.vue** in **src/components/Pages/Admin/Countries.vue** I want to import it in a file name **Add_Doctor.vue** in **src/components/Pages/Admin/Doctors/Add_Doctor.vue**.

I used `import Contries from './components/Pages/Admin/Countries'`
But i give me an error **module not found**
how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can import both ways

```
import Countries from './components/Pages/Admin/Countries.vue'

import Countries  from '@/components/Pages/Admin/Countries.vue'
```

Comment: I added a picture. It may help

Comment: Check now. It should be 'Countries' instead of  'Contries'

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import Contries from '../Countries.vue'

// @ is an alias to /src
```

Comment: I added a picture. It may help

Answer (score 0):

try below one
`import Countries from './components/Pages/Admin/Countries.vue'`

I think you are missing `Countries.vue` in the end

Comment: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/Pages/Admin/Countries.vue'

Comment: I added a picture. It may help

Comment: I updated the answer. there is a spelling mistake. you used `country-name` as `Countries`. But you import it as `Contries`. Use `Countries` there